# mariabackup trouble between Windows and Linux

Tags: replication, backup, mariadb

I am finally trying to migrate a database from Windows to Linux.

I am running MariaDB 10.4 (I have also tried mariabackup from 10.4.22 too)

I do this:

```
mariabackup --backup --target-dir=e:\transport --user=username --password=datpwtho
```

Then I copy the resulting files over to the Linux host.

I then run:

```
mariabackup --prepare --target-dir=.
mariabackup --copy-back --target-dir=.
```

Which copies the files to /var/lib/mysql on the destination Linux host.

I then run:

```
chown mysql:mysql -R /var/lib/mysql
service mariadb start
```

Every time I do this process I get this error on the Linux host:

[ERROR] InnoDB: corrupted TRX_NO 62f900540074096f
[Note] InnoDB: Retry with innodb_force_recovery=5

and MariaDB will not start

We don't actually use DB transactions in our system so I can assure you that there are no corrupted transactions. I've also done mysqlcheck on the source server and everything checks out fine.

Does anyone have *any* idea what is going on?

The whole point of using mariabackup in my case is because I want to replicate the source to the destination while the migration is in process. So I don't really want to just mysqldump / restore the data but I suppose I will if that is the only way.

Comment: What Windows version are you moving from?

Comment: I would consider a source dump, such as with `mysqldump` or `mariadb-dump`, instead.

Comment: I was following the replication guide on mariadb website and it said mariabackup would pretty much automate it. Does mariabackup just not work?

Comment: Does it make a difference if you do the prepare on the Windows side? In most tested cases of data and mariabackup it does work so unfortunately you have found a bug. [Bug reports](https://jira.mariadb.org) are welcome, and I got a hint that it might be full text index related if you have those. Everything DML in InnoDB is a transaction even if its a single statement.

Comment: I tried doing it on windowsbut I also filed a bug report.